# How to overload the "import" in Python to name a function "import" for the Cement framework

Tags: python, import, syntax, command-line-interface, cement

How to overload the "import" in Python to name a function "import" for the Cement framework:

So, I am working on a CLI Python project that utilizes the Cement CLI framework. When creating commands for the command line in Cement, what you name the function that is run becomes the name of the command. I need to have a command that is called "import", but for obvious reasons, I cannot name a function "import" in Python.

Does anyone know a creative work around for naming a function "import" in Python? I tried some creative "duck typing" to try and overload import, but that did not work.

Comment: I'll bet there's a way to specify the command name explicitly, to get around problems like this.

Comment: _How to overload the "import" in Python_ You can't.  `import` isn't a builtin function like `list` or `print` that can be reassigned; it's a _keyword_, which is a whole different ballgame.

Answer (score 0):

@racerj93 this is actually possible by setting the `label` keyword argument to `expose()` (alias: `ex()` )

```
    @ex(
        label='import'
    )
    def import_cmd(self):
        print("Inside Base.import_cmd()")
```

You can then call:

```
myapp import
```

Ref:

- https://cement.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api/ext/ext_argparse/#cement.ext.ext_argparse.expose